# Stuck on using WKB to solve $\epsilon\frac{d^2u}{dx^2}-x(1+x)\frac{du}{dx}+xu=0$ as $\epsilon\to 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, asymptotics

I want to use the WKB method to solve the uniform leading order approximation for the ODE
$$\epsilon\frac{d^2u}{dx^2}-x(1+x)\frac{du}{dx}+xu=0,~u(-0.5)=\alpha,~u(0.5)=\beta$$

My attempt:

Let $u(x)\approx\exp\left(\frac{1}{\epsilon}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\epsilon^nS_n(x)\right)$, then we can compute $u'(x)$ and $u''(x)$. And finally I have

$$\epsilon\left[\frac{1}{\epsilon ^2}\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\epsilon^nS_n'(x)\right)^2+\frac{1}{\epsilon}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\epsilon^nS_n''(x)\right]-x(1+x)\left(\frac{1}{\epsilon}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\epsilon^nS_n'(x)\right)+x=0$$.

However I'm not sure how to continue the proccess. How to deal with the $x$ terms? And how to finish computing these all messing stuffs? Need some help!

PS:
I know the finally answer shall be $u(x)\approx2\alpha(x+1)+(\beta-3\alpha)\exp^{\frac{6x-3}{8\epsilon}}$

Comment: You match terms with the same powers of $\epsilon$. So start with $\epsilon^0$.